# Same-site iframes not able to connect in Django

Tags: html, django, iframe

The iframe displays that it cannot connect. I've tried using the default `@xframe_options_exempt` decorator on the view, aswell as django-csp's `@csp_exempt` to no avail.

The console errors given are:

`Refused to display 'http://localhost:8000/new_pull/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

and
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

view

```
@csp_exempt
@login_required
def new_pull(request):
    """Create a new pull request"""

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form
        form = PullForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data
        form = PullForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_pull = form.save(commit=False)
            new_pull.owner = request.user
            new_pull.save()

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_pull.html', context)
```

base.html

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <br>

        <iframe src="{% url 'learning_logs:new_pull' %}" title="Pull request Iframe"></iframe>
        <iframe src="learning_logs/new_pull.html" title="Pull request Iframe"></iframe>
    {% endif %}
```

new_pull.html

```
<div class="pull container text-center border-top mt-5">
    <h5 class="mt-2">Pull request</h5>

    <p>New pull request:</p>
     <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_pull' %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}

        {% buttons %}
        <button name="submit" class="btn btn-green pl-2 pr-2">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            Create pull
        </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next"
        value="{% url 'learning_logs:bug_tracker' %}" />
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe you are providing the wrong information in your question. This seems like it is an HTML question -- not a Django question. I do not think your Python code is relevant here. Instead, post your console error message exactly as written that tells you you cannot load the iframe.

Comment: Thanks, I've added that into the question.

Comment: Please post django-csp related values from your settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to `Settings.py`:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

By default, `the X-Frame-Options` are set to `Deny`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/clickjacking/

---

This may not be your problem, as there are many things that could be causing this, such as CSP. Difficult to say for sure without my information.

Answer (score 0):

First good to mention the documentation of the django-csp [Configuring django-csp](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

Try to do first what's bones225 mentioned.
Esure header `X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN';` Note, you can check all your current headers in Response Headers in the Web Developer Tools (chrome: Network -> Name -> click on html page -> Headers will open on right side )

You may have directive `CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'")` in place and no `CSP_FRAME_SRC` set.
Then add `CSP_FRAME_SRC = ('localhost:8000')` too.